# Unable to load class [oracle.jdbc.driver.Oracle Driver]

Tags: hibernate, oracle10g

I am working on an application involving hibernate. 
I am getting this exception when I invoke my application:

> **org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException:
>   Unable to load class [oracle.jdbc.driver.Oracle   Driver]**   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:245)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:200)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:156)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:95)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
>     at
>   com.infy.EPP.resources.HibernateUtility.createSessionFactory(HibernateUtility.java:36)
>     at
>   com.infy.EPP.dao.BankLocationDAOImpl.getListOfBanks(BankLocationDAOImpl.java:27)
>     at
>   com.infy.EPP.business.service.BankLocationServiceImpl.getListOfBanks(BankLocationServiceImpl.java:20)
>     at
>   com.infy.EPP.web.managedbeans.BankLocationBean.(BankLocationBean.java:53)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
>     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)  at
>   com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:186)
>     at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:100)     at
>   com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
>     at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)    at
>   com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:257)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:117)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
>     at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:71)
>     at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:160)    at
>   org.apache.el.parser.AstEqual.getValue(AstEqual.java:37)  at
>   org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression.getValue(JspValueExpression.java:106)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:457)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1850)
>     at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.doRenderView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:431)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:232)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   com.infy.EPP.web.filter.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class :
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.Oracle Driver  at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:230)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:242)
>     ... 72 more

This is the hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
    <!-- hibernate dialect -->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.Oracle    Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">system</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">oracle</property>
    <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>

    <!-- Automatic schema creation (begin) === -->
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</property>

    <!-- Simple memory-only cache -->
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- <property name="show_sql">true</property> -->  



        <mapping class="com.infy.EPP.entites.LoginEntity" />


</session-factory>
```

This is Hibernate Utility file:

```
public class HibernateUtility 
{

    private static final String CONFIGURATION_LOCATION = "com/infy/EPP/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml";
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    public synchronized static SessionFactory createSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) 
        {
            try {
                // Step1 : Loading the configuration details from
                // hibernate.cfg.xml
                Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
                        .configure(CONFIGURATION_LOCATION);
System.out.println("configuration in Utility=="+configuration); //---//syso1

                // Step2 : Creating ServiceRegistry using the
                // StandardServiceRegistryBuilder and Configuration defined in
                // Step 1

                serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                        .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
                System.out.println("serviceRegistry=="+serviceRegistry); ---//syso 2

                // Step3 : Creating the SessionFactory using the Configuration
                // and serviceRegistry.

                sessionFactory = configuration
                        .buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
                System.out.println("sessionFactory==="+sessionFactory);   ---//syso 3


            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
                EppLogger.logError("HibernateUtility",
                        "createSessionFactory", e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

This is the DAO class method where I invoke it:

```
public Login authorize(Login to) throws Exception 
    {
        LoginEntity le = null;
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
        Session session = null;
        Login login =null;
        try {
            sessionFactory = HibernateUtility.createSessionFactory();
            session=sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            le = (LoginEntity)session.get(LoginEntity.class, to.getUserId());
            if (le != null) 
            {
                 login = new Login();
                login.setPassword(le.getPassword());
                login.setRole(le.getRole());
                login.setStatus(le.getStatus());
                login.setUserId(le.getUserId());
            }
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            }
        catch (PersistenceException exception) {
            EppLogger.logError(this.getClass().getName(), "authorize",
                    exception.getMessage());
            throw new Exception("DAO.TECHNICAL_ERROR");
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            EppLogger.logError(this.getClass().getName(), "authorize", e.getMessage());
            throw new Exception("DAO.TECHNICAL_ERROR");
        } 
        finally 
        {
            if(session!=null)
            {
            session.close();
            sessionFactory.close();
            }
        }
        return login;
    }
```

I have ojdbc7 under lib folder. Still it is not working.
I have gone through several pages on SO which suggest to add ojdbc14 in classpath. Still didn't work out

UPDATE:
I have put some syso statements in Hibernate Utility file. I am getting value of first 2 but not the 3rd syso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appears to be a space in driver_class property.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.Oracle    Driver</property>
```

Even the error message suggests that.

Try by removing the space

That is,

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
```

Comment: After removing the space the exception has changed as "Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]"

Comment: Hibernate doc says – you should create the session factory once in the
lifetime of the application and its only in the end when you are exiting
the program you should close it off.

I would recommend you read more on SessionFactory and how/when to close it.

For Quick fix: remove sessionFactory.close(); from everywhere in the
program

Comment: Thanks! I will go through it